# How to select spring bean to call at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

*Original title: How to declarativly configure multiple beans for the same interface and select the correct one at runtime*

I had a project lately which had the following demand for the web application to be implemented:

When a user logs on to the system she will specify a scope (B2C, B2B). While she is working with the application some calls to backend systems must be routed to different instances of the backend systems based on the scope of the current login.

The webapplication consists of two parts (SPA in the front, Spring Boot Application with REST Endpoints in the back) and a collection of instances of backend systems, for example an archive for B2C and one archive for B2B.

The current implementation handles the REST Requests and decides on the scope of the login which archive to call. This works but I want to make it declarative instead of explicite coding. So it should be easy to add a new backend instance for a different scope.

For starters I'd like to define two beans, one for the access to the B2C archive and one for the access to the B2B archive. Both will implement the same interface; actually they are instances of the same class with different config values.

When the REST call is handled, I'd like spring to choose the correct bean to be called based on the scope of the current login (B2C or B2B).

I had different ideas how to solve this (Scoped Proxies, AOP, custom `AutowireCandidateResolver`, Object Pools) but currently i'm stuck and can't say whether i'm on the right track here.

Has anybody done something like that already?

## Update

Thanks to [Fritz Duchardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385808/fritz-duchardt) and [Ken Bekov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4544823/ken-bekov) for the idea to use Factories + Scoped Proxies and return them to the calling code.

## Update 2

I just implemented a spring extension that is capable of running the following test (fullcode here: https://gitlab.com/thuri/service-provider-proxy).

The inner classes are just to keep the test together. It should also work when they are in separat files.

The main point is, that the Interface is implemented by two different beans and spring decides at runtime which bean should actually handle the call by evaluating the spEL expression in the Annotations

```java
  @Test
  public void testProxiedResourceInjectionWithField() {

    caseSwitch.switchValue = "B2B";
    assertEquals("Well you know ... ", client.proxiedService.doCoolStuff());

    caseSwitch.switchValue = "B2C";
    assertEquals("This will do ...", client.proxiedService.doCoolStuff());
  }


  public static class ProxiedServiceClient {
    @Autowired 
    public ProxiedServiceInterface proxiedService;
  }

  @ServiceProviderProxy
  public static interface ProxiedServiceInterface {
    public String doCoolStuff();
  }

  @ProxiedService(expression = "#{switch.switchValue == 'B2B'}")
  public static class B2BServiceImpl implements ProxiedServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public String doCoolStuff() {
      return "Well you know ... ";
    }
  }

  @ProxiedService(expression = "#{switch.switchValue == 'B2C'}")
  public static class B2CServiceImpl implements ProxiedServiceInterface {
    @Override
    public String doCoolStuff() {
      return "This will do ...";
    }
  }

  public static class CaseSwitch {
    public String switchValue = "";
  }
```

Comment: I would create a factory bean that implements logic of choosing of appropriate bean. Then I would inject this factory to controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This could be made to work with a [Spring Factory Bean](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean) that has been set to [request or session scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes), e.g.:

```
@Bean(name = "archive")
@Scope(value= "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public ArchiveFactory archiveFactory() {
    ArchiveFactory factory = new ArchiveFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

Spring will use AOP Proxies to create new beans at runtime, e.g. at every request, using your factory bean implementation. You could use a thread local to pass the current context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think it's a good answer when the beans you like to access are short lived and easy to create. But when the 2 archive beans are singletons (one for each archive) because it's hard and slow to create them (because of the connection they contain), it's not sufficient. But it's a good idea with which i can start: Pass in the ThreadLocal, check the context and select the bean which is appropriate.